# Convert mp3 to base64 - File Reader

Tags: javascript, cordova, audio, base64, media

I am developing an app which needs to record audio, and then have the audio stored as part of an object, and uploaded to a database.
I am trying to alert the base64 of the file first just to ensure it has been found correctly.
I am using the cordova media capture plugin to access the recorder on a device, and am able to record the audio, however once it has been recorded I want to convert into a base64 format before sending to the database. When I use this method it alerts the base64, but it is empty, just "data:audio/mpeg;base64," with nothing after, I do not know why it isn't converting the file correctly.

Plugin: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media-capture

```
function captureSuccess(capturedFiles) {

    //Convert capturedFiles[0] into var containing file as base64

    previewFile(capturedFiles);


    alert("Audio Captured");
}

function captureError() {
    alert("Audio Not Captured");
}

navigator.device.capture.captureAudio(captureSuccess, captureError, {
    limit: 1,
    duration: 20
    });
});

 /***********************************************************************************/

function previewFile(files) {
  var preview = document.querySelector('img');
  var file    = files[0];
  var reader  = new FileReader();

  reader.onload = function () {
  alert(reader.result);
  };

  if (file) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having alot of issues to this, and had looked all over StackOverFlow for an answer but had alot of trouble finding one, so for anyone in the future who has this issue I was able to solve it. The issue was that the file I wanted to convert to base64 had a "start" and an "end" which were both set the 0, so none of the bytes were being accessed. To ensure the bytes are accessed I keep the start byte as 0 (so don't change anything), and set the end byte to the same as the file size. Here is the resolved code below:

```
$("#btnAudio").click(function () {


     function captureSuccess(capturedFiles) {

        var path = capturedFiles[0].fullPath;
        //Convert capturedFiles[0] into var containing file as base64

        previewFile(capturedFiles);


        alert("Audio Captured");
    }

    function captureError() {
        alert("Audio Not Captured");
    }

    navigator.device.capture.captureAudio(captureSuccess, captureError, {
        limit: 1,
        duration: 20
    });
});

/***********************************************************************************/

function previewFile(files) {
    var file = files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    file.end = file.size;
    var preview = document.querySelector('audio');

    reader.onload = function () {

/*For testing I am just alerting reader.result, but if you want to store the 
base64 just create a var and set its value to reader.result*/

        alert(reader.result); 
    };
    if (file) {
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
}
```